# Getting a fail build because of an NSArray line error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6, nsarray, nsarraycontroller

When trying to build my xcode project, I get an error at this line:

```
- (NSArray<H24CommercialSlide * >*)allSlides;
```

Giving me a Parse issue: Expected '>' & Expected ')'

Not sure how to resolve this issue and what has changed in xcode that makes this previously working code fail.

Any ideas?

Full code snippet:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class H24CommercialSlide;

@protocol H24SlidesProviderProtocol <NSObject>
- (NSArray<H24CommercialSlide * >*)allSlides;
@end

@interface H24SlidesProvider : NSObject<H24SlidesProviderProtocol>

@end
```

Comment: It's for an image slider inside the app, added the rest of the code snippet

Comment: Which version of Xcode do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightweight generics were introduced in Xcode 7. Install Xcode 7 or change

```
- (NSArray<H24CommercialSlide * >*)allSlides;
```

to

```
- (NSArray*)allSlides;
```